# MediaPlayer class sometimes not working in Android KitKat 4.4

Tags: android

I have an inexplicable problem using MediaPlayer class in Android 4.4 KitKat. In my activity, I implement Google Play Services locationlistener. Evertyme location is changed, I call a function with this statements:

```
    Resources res1 = ctext.getResources();
    int soundId1 = res1.getIdentifier("ik", "raw",
            ctext.getPackageName());

    Resources res2 = ctext.getResources();
    int soundId2 = res2.getIdentifier(prefix, "raw", ctext.getPackageName());

    myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctext, soundId1);
    myMediaPlayerNode = MediaPlayer.create(ctext, soundId2);

    myMediaPlayerNode.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
            myMediaPlayerNode.stop();

            // play next audio file

        }

    });

    myMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
            myMediaPlayer.stop();

            myMediaPlayerNode.start();

            // play next audio file

        }

    });

    myMediaPlayer.start();
```

This works fine on all devices, except on a Samsung Galaxy s5 with android 4.4 kitkat. When I call the method outside de onlocationchanged event, it works fine. Is there something wrong with the mediamanager in android 4.4?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20555675/1777090)

Comment: What is the value of `prefix`? Why do you use two separate Resources fields?

Comment: @MysticMagic: I think in Android 4.4 there is an issue with using MediaPlayer in the locationchanged event. When I try to play the file when the locationlistener is off, it works.